# java sql empty fields

Tags: java, sql

Hi i am trying to execute query

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(location_query);
```

location_query is

```
insert into table(col, col2) value("2", "");
```

Both col and col2 are double(12,2) type, i get error
`Data truncated for column 'col2' at row 1`, but if I print my query and copy, and paste it to PMA (PhpMyAdmin) its correct.

I guesst that its becouse value of col2 is empty, but is there chance to solve this in other way not to checking all variables which im trying to put to my query ??

Comment: no its not default null, but I can change it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, an empty String is not a valid number, therefore different database systems might handle that differently. When you just want that column NULL or filled with the default, you should leave it out like this:

```
insert into table(col) value(2);
```

OR set it NULL explicitly:

```
insert into table(col, col2) value(2, NULL);
```

Besides, numbers are written without quotes in SQL. Furthermore, you should cosider using [PreparedStatements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) only. PreparedStatements give you type saftly and protect from SQL injection and might be faster when reused.

Take a look at [google "statement vs. preparedstatement"](http://www.google.de/search?q=java%20statement%20vs%20preparedstatement)

**EDIT**

Your example would look something like this, when using prepared statements:

```
String yourFirstString = "2.34";
String yourSecondString = "";

double yourFirstDouble = 0;
double yourSecondDouble = 0;

if(yourFirstString  != null && yourFirstString.trim().length() > 0){
  try {
     yourFirstDouble = Double.parseDouble(yourFirstString); 
  }catch(NumberFormatException e){
    // handle Exception here
  }
}

// same parsing for the second double

PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into table (col, col2) value(?, ?)");
stmt.setDouble(1, yourFirstDouble);
stmt.setDouble(2, yourSecondDouble);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Ok, but will preparedStatements protect me against empty values ?? and secound thing is that i never know which value is empty thats why I have to put all of them

Comment: Since ´setDouble(int, double)´ is type save you can only use valid doubles as argument. That means, you can not apply an empty String to that Statement. You should test if the String is empty and and if so, set 0 or NULL. Otherwise, you should try to parse the String into a double and use it. I'll edit my answer and add an example.

Comment: I added some parsing example. However, all that logic should not be in the same place. The parsing of the values, user entries I would guess, should be validated when entered somewhere near the GUI logic. The database layer however, should only get doubles and not do string parsing, validation and the like.